# Gradle 1.1 - create jar matching folder structure of sourceSets

Tags: jar, gradle, executable-jar

I'm at the point where I can use sourceSets{ } to compile java source code with dependencies & pack additional resources into the jar gradle builds as well as modify the manifest.mf attributes, but I can't figure out how to customize the folder structure of the produced jar. I would ideally prefer to put the directory stucture my source sets followed - /java for java classes and /conf for additional resources. How would I do this in gradle 1.1?

Comment: If you put your classes under `/java` wouldn't that prevent class loader from finding your classes? Surely when classloader looks for `com.example.Main` class it looks for `com/example/Main.class`? Maybe I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

You'd add your own Jar task and configure it accordingly. However, I'm not quite sure what such a Jar would be useful for. Standard class loaders wouldn't be able to make sense of it.